# Select2 load default data in multiple select with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 4.0.0.

```
<select id="mySelect" class="form-control" multiple="multiple"></select>
$('#mySelect').select2({
      width: '100%',
      data: data,
      ajax: {
           url: function() { return 'myendpoint' ; },
           dataType: 'json',
           delay: 250,
           data: function (params) {
               return {
                   where: {'title' : '%' + params.term + '%'}, 
                       page: params.page
               };
          },
          processResults: function (data, params) {

            params.page = params.page || 1;
            return {
                results: $.map(data.message.data, function (item) {
                     return {
                          text: item.values.title,
                          id: item.values.id
                     }
                }),
                pagination: {
                     more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                   }
               };
           },
           cache: true
           },
           minimumInputLength: 1,

       }).val(ids).trigger('change');
```

This is what i'm tring to do but it seems that it overrides data i'm passing during the inizialization.
If I remove the ajax everything seems to work right.
My data is an array of object:

```
[
    { id: '1', text: 'example' }
]
```

Instead my ids is an array of id [1].

I checkout some other issues in stackoverflow, but others has some different version and use initSelection but it seems don't work in select2 4.0.0.

Where i'm wrong with this?
Thanks.